# C++ MFC: Draw a bitmap into a CFrame

Tags: c++, mfc, bitblt

I am trying to draw a bitmap (stored as an array of bytes) to a window.

Typical procedure follows:

Get the device context in the OnPaint() handler.

```
CPaintDC dc(this);
```

Create a compatible device context from it,

```
CDC pMemDC->CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
```

Create a compatible bitmap that is the size of the client area (`GetClientRect(&WinRect)`).

```
CBitmap pNewBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(&dc, WinRect.Width(), WinRect.Height());
```

Now, if the window client size is exactly the same size as the bitmap, I can simply make a call to `pNewBitmap->SetBitmapBits` to "feed" my array into the bitmap.

Follow this with a `BitBlt` and the bitmap appears on the window.

```
dc->BitBlt(0, 0, WinRect.Width(), WinRect.Height(), pMemDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

If you want the window size to vary independent of the image size, then first you must make sure `pNewBitmap` is the right size (the client rectangle), but now you cannot simply shove the array into the bitmap.

In this situation, I have found a solution by repeating the above procedure to create a bitmap the exact size of the image so I can "shove" my bits into it, and then `BitBlt` that into the larger, client-sized bitmap, which then gets `BitBlt`'ed into the window.

Is there another way to do this? Actual code follows.

```
void CAnimateWnd::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    DrawScene(&dc);

    // Do not call CWnd::OnPaint() for painting messages
}

void CAnimateWnd::DrawScene(CDC *pDrawDC)
{
    CRect WinRect;
    GetClientRect(&WinRect);

    if (pNewBitmap == NULL)
    {
        pMemDC = new CDC();
        pMemDC->CreateCompatibleDC(pDrawDC);
        pNewBitmap = new CBitmap();
        pNewBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDrawDC, WinRect.Width(), WinRect.Height());
        pMemDC->SelectObject(pNewBitmap);
    }

    CRect BMPRect;
    GetBitmapDrawSize(&BMPRect);
    if (BMPRect != NULL)
    {
        if (!(BMPRect.Width() >= WinRect.Width() && BMPRect.Height() >= WinRect.Height()))
        {
            //The bitmap is smaller than the window, so fill the window with the background color.
            CBrush BackBrush(BackGndColor);
            CPen BackPen(PS_SOLID, 1, BackGndColor);
            pMemDC->SelectObject(&BackBrush);
            pMemDC->SelectObject(&BackPen);
            pMemDC->Rectangle(&WinRect);
            BackBrush.DeleteObject();
            BackPen.DeleteObject();
        }
    }

    OverrideAndDrawInHere(pMemDC, resize);
    pDrawDC->BitBlt(0,0,WinRect.right,WinRect.bottom,pMemDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
}

template <class T>
void ImageWindow<T>::OverrideAndDrawInHere(CDC *pDC, int resize)
{
    if (this->sourceImage == NULL) return;

    CRect clientRect;
    GetClientRect(&clientRect);

    if (this->dispBMP == NULL)
    {
        this->dispDC = new CDC();
        this->dispDC->CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
        this->dispBMP = new CBitmap();
        this->dispBMP->CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, this->sourceImage->GetWidth(), this->sourceImage->GetHeight());
        this->dispDC->SelectObject(this->dispBMP);
    }

    this->dispBMP->SetBitmapBits(this->sourceImage->GetArea() * 4, this->translatedImage);
    pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, this->sourceImage->GetWidth(), this->sourceImage->GetHeight(), this->dispDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using BitBlt try [StretchBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd145120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if you want to paint a bitmap to a window that isn't the same size as source image:

From MSDN:

> Copies a bitmap from a source rectangle into a destination rectangle,
>   stretching or compressing the bitmap if necessary to fit the
>   dimensions of the destination rectangle.

If you want the same results as you've shown then you're probably doing it the best way. You could use something like FillRect to draw directly to the Frame (or handle OnEraseBkgnd) and then BitBlt the original sized image but you'd get probably get some flickering, which your double-buffered solution solves.

Comment: The problem is painting a bitmap that is smaller than the window, without stretching it, and still painting the rest of the window with a solid filler color.